# Slide Right to Left and Left to Right (Not working)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am wondering why [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hcmLw/2354/) is perfectly working but in my server, it doesn't work. Have a look at the following code below:

HTML

```
<div class="project">
    <div class="project-col2">
        <div class="project-mid-box">
            <ul>
                <a class="myButton"> <li> Project List 1  </li> </a> 
                <a class="myButton"> <li> Project List 2  </li> </a> 
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="project-col3 myDiv">
        <div class="project-mid-box">
            <p> HERE </p>
        </div>
    </div>  

</div>
```

CSS

```
.project {overflow:hidden;}
.project h3 {color:#FFF;font-weight:normal;}
.project-col2 {float:left;width:50%;position:relative;}
.project-col3 {float:left;width:30%;position:relative;}
.project-mid-box {padding-left:10px;}
.project-mid-box ul li {border:1px solid #CCC;margin:2px 0;border-radius:5px;padding:5px;line-height:25px;}
.project-mid-box ul li:hover {background-color:#f7f7f7;
.myDiv {display:none;}
```

JS -- I have added a function because in JSfiddle is automatically added.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(".myButton").click(function () {
        // Set the effect type
        var effect = 'slide'; 
        // Set the options for the effect type chosen
        var options = { direction: 'right' };
        // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
        var duration = 700;
        $('.myDiv').toggle(effect, options, duration);
    });
})  
</script>
```

Lastly, i didn't forget to get external source jquery library

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"> </script>
```

It should be totally working on my server, but it's not working at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: You're including two jQuery libs, you only need one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading 2 versions of the main jQuery library but not jQueryUI. The jQueryUI resources on code.jQuery.com are in the `ui` directory.

Example http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js

I can see possible confusion since there is a common version number so all you need is to add in the `/ui/` directory to what you have

Comment: I only have UI Datatable. I dont think it will get affected. By the way, can you double check the external sources in JSfiddle above? It could be a problem if I am not using the same source? Because I am using the latest jquery library. @charlietfl

Comment: right but `effect` is jQueryUI. If you remove that you could get rid of jQueryUI. look at errors thrown in console

Comment: can you help me to get the real jquery to make it sliding? I use that link and it appears but not sliding. @charlietfl

Comment: ok, `effect` is doing that from jQueryUI. you would need to use `animate` if you remove jQueryUI

Comment: Alright, I am getting confused and more confused. The one and only I put into my server is `http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js`. That one is jQueryUI. It should be animated right? But I tried and it's not working thou. It appears but not sliding like JSFIDDLE above. Am I missing again?

Comment: you need both files to make jQueryUI work. jQuery UI depends on jQuery core

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 main jQuery so not working your code. use one main jQuery 1.11.2 then try.

Comment: actually since no plugins were registered to first version, oddly enough having 2 wouldn't cause page too break or cause any errors. It's not right for sure though. Second version will just overwrite the whole jQuery object

Answer (score 0):

Use this library function you are calling in your code is related to this library

```
` <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>`
```